# iOS 9 Error write .plist

Tags: objective-c, plist, ios9

My App errors after update to iOS 9. Can't write .plist file in project.

```
-(BOOL)writeDictionaryToPlist:(NSDictionary*)plistDict {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"History" ofType:@"plist"];

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:plistDict];

    NSDictionary *saveDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict];
    BOOL result = [saveDict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

    return result;
}
```

`result` is `NO`.

But iOS 7 and iOS 8 is works fine.

How I can fix it ?

Comment: This code won't work under any version of iOS, at least not on a real device. The app's bundle is read-only.

Comment: BTW - the use of `dict` is pointless. Just call `writeToFile:` on `plistDict` (once you have a valid path).

Answer (score 0):

Use dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: to write to dictionary from plist

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"History" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
BOOL result = [dict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

**NOTE** since plist is the app resource you cant write to that file, hence create a plist file in your documents directory and write to that file.

```
NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
path = [path stringByAppendingString:@"/History.plist"];
BOOL result = [dict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Retrieve the data from plist

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

**UPDATE**
Add NSAppTransportSecurity as a dictionary and  the first child should be a bool named NSAllowsArbitraryLoads set to YES.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Comment: Do not use `stringByAppendingString:` to build the path. Use `stringByAppendingPathComponent:`.

Comment: Hi Mahanthesh Kumbar Thank you for support I follow this answer and I got some error msg BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20) _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid name (15) How I fix it ?

Comment: check the updated answer, add NSAppTransportSecurity to plist file